# Is there anything that MUST be done on a multi-core CPU?

Tags: computation-models, cpu, multi-tasking

When considering how multi-thread-friendly our program must be, my team puzzled about whether there's anything that *absolutely cannot be done* on a single-core CPU. I posited that graphics processing requires massively parallel processing, but they argue that things like DOOM were done on single-core CPUs without GPUs.

**Is there anything that *must* be done on a multi-core processor?**

Assume there is infinite time for both development and running.

Comment: While the answers below seem to largely be “no”, there are historically systems that literally couldn't have worked without a co-processor handling some tasks.  One strong example I know of is the Nintendo DS, which includes an 67MHz ARM9 CPU and a 33MHz ARM7 CPU (also used for back-compat when playing GBA games).  For DS games, the ARM7 handles playing audio & Wi-Fi communication because the ARM9 can't process & draw anything of note to the screen while keeping up with feeding audio to the sound chip directly.  So as @jmite states “under what constraints”, lack of speed can req multiple CPUs.

Comment: At my job we use multicore Xeons and the Xenomai real-time Linux extensions to do low-latency audio processing.  We have a three-stage audio processing pipeline, and each stage gets its own dedicated core, which it uses ~70% of the cycles of.  Non-real-time tasks get to use the fourth core, and whatever cycles are leftover on the first three.  This would only be possible on a single-core CPU if that single core was 3+ times faster than a core on current 4-core CPU; given that the current CPU runs at 2GHz, that might be difficult to achieve.

Comment: Software on a single-core CPU can emulate a multi-core CPU. The difference is almost entirely speed.

Comment: One thing that *must be done* on a multi core system is testing multithreaded software. Because some defects will (almost) never happen on a single-core system. I'm not sure that qualifies as an answer, though...

Comment: @nikie A single-core system can emulate memory ordering and stale caches too - but I imagine this would be *extremely* inefficient (like 10× slowdown)

Comment: @nikie: non-realtime multicore virtual machine running on single-core host?

Comment: How about: "Running more than one infinite loops"?

Comment: @MartínValdésdeLeón: Any preemptive multithreading system can do that on a single-core CPU.

Comment: @Nayuki: You're right, of course. A multicore CPU is still deterministic and computable, so in theory you can emulate it with a single-core abacus. Given enough time. The comment was meant as real-world experience. If you write multithreaded software, you'd better test it on a multicore system.

Comment: Early 3D games like Doom were done by massively clever code optimization and computational short cuts. How much time are we willing to spend on developing and implementing those types of optimizations?  I guess it totally depends on what you are developing and it's purpose.

Comment: it is possible there are contrived problems (ie indicating affirmative answer where distributed computing is "forced") involving cryptography etc. also Bitcoin distributed transactions (based on Byzantine generals problem) is a decent response. its not that the processing couldnt be done on a central server, but that its distributed to help with centralized security problems aka "avoid cheating/ corruption". so maybe something along that vein. see also [Paxos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paxos_(computer_science)). (might try to cook this up into answer later esp with indication of support.)

Comment: Yes - consider responding in real-time to simultaneous requests - you could certainly queue the requests in some sort of buffer, but then it's not real-time

Comment: @user2813274 It's not like it's a question of "real-time" vs. "non-real-time" - it's a spectrum. Looking at a VGA display? Real-time means "be able to produce an image 60 times per second". Communicating over COM? 56 kbit/s or so is real-time. A web page or a distributed data cluster? Once a minute might still clasify as real-time - in fact, I've seen systems that only update once an hour and are still classified as real-time (in contrast to the inferior systems that only update once a day :)). It's just about context.

Comment: @Luaan "responding" is different than "outputting data at rate X" - let's keep it simple and say you have a binary input pin, and when it changes you need to change the state of a corresponding binary output pin - now scale it up to multiple input and output pins, and you end up needing a multi-core system in order to keep it real-time and not miss any "changes" (assuming the input pin can switch states as fast as your CPU clock speed, anything slower can result in missed changes).

Comment: @user2813274 The rate at which the inputs and outputs can change is the determining factor. That's not unique to computers - every process is sensitive to that. If your inputs can only change once in 1/200th of a second, even a normal Windows application on a single CPU can be considered real-time. If they can change a trillion times a second, even a transistor is too slow to be real-time. Even pure hardware audio processing gives you output lag (which in turn has been used as a desirable effect, of course), and we still consider them "real-time". Again, it's a spectrum of real-time-ness.

Comment: Inputs being faster than the processor can handle: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8NPzLBSBzPI

Comment: Please accompany any downvotes with a comment explaining how I can ask a better question in the future 

Answer (score 48, accepted):

If you don't care about the running time, anything you can do on a multi-core machine, you can do on a single-core machine.  A multi-core machine is just a way of speeding up some kinds of computations.

If you can solve a problem in time $T$ on a multi-core machine with $n$ cores, then you can solve it time $\sim Tn$ (or less look at [Amdahl's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amdahl%27s_law)) on a single-core machine.  The single-core machine can emulate a multi-core machine using time-slicing / [time-sharing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-sharing).

Comment: I am not entirely sure that is absolutely correct. I don't think memory consistency bugs are possible to generate on a single core (Yes, one could emulate a multicache system on a unicore, but such indirection is kind of cheating.). (Perhaps an equivalent of implementing reg. swap by move ops in a VLIW, exploiting guaranteed ||ism?) I suppose that even on a single-threaded core it would still be possible to extract entropy from multithreaded timing variability, but the amount of entropy would be smaller per unit time (which is really just a matter of performance like the other differences).

Comment: @PaulA.Clayton Memory consistency bugs are usually unwanted and well-written software should not exhibit them. However, if you **really** wanted to, you could emulate them on a single CPU. (Although it might be slow)

Comment: Sometimes the time on a single core will be more than $n$ times longer than on an $n$-core machine, for instance for searching with random restarts or if the pieces fit into cache on the multiple cores but not on the single core.

Comment: _"The single-core machine can emulate a multi-core machine using time-slicing / time-sharing."_ And indeed have done so since the dawn of the "modern" Operating System.

Comment: @AndrásSalamon That is indeed explained in my answer

Comment: @PaulA.Clayton I think you could get memory consistency problems (like a non-atomic increment) if you were to have two different processes that both modified the same shared memory.  You just need pre-emptive multi-tasking.  Of course, this is generally why modern OSes don't have processes sharing the same writable memory unless they explicitly ask to.

Comment: @PatrickM Atomicity with respect to interrupts is not the same thing as memory consistency (especially as such typically involves a single memory location whereas memory consistency concerns temporal ordering of accesses to different locations). While one could emulate a multicache system (I *specifically* disqualified such as "cheating"), a single thread, single cache system is inherently sequentially consistent.

Comment: @PaulA.Clayton Ah.  I thought you meant consistency between threads in general, not the consistency of the CPU cache.

Comment: Despite the fact that it's not the most up-voted, I'm accepting this one because I find it to be the clearest-worded answer, that also sums up what all other answers are saying. That said, if someone somehow comes up with an answer that definitively proves there's something that we all agree can _not_ be done on one core, I'll have to accept that instead :)

Comment: Theory: process intends to have two cores each modify adjacent bits of the same byte, simultaneously, then each core also reads the whole byte. Process has a trigger that fires if they don't both read the same value from the byte. If each thread's write and subsequent read are somehow written to prevent a single core from slicing between the two steps (thus preventing one core from doing both writes, then both reads), would that qualify? Granted, I don't know if that's actually possible, nor what application there might be (other than, perhaps, "detect multi-core environment").

Answer (score 58):

The question is: under what constraints?

There are certainly problems where, if we ask the question "can we solve this problem on hardware X in the given amount of time", the answer will be no.

But this is not a "future-proof" answer: things which in the past could not be done fast enough in a single core probably can be now, and we can't predict what future hardware will be capable of.

In terms of computability, we know that a single-tape Turing Machine is capable of computing all the same functions as a single or multi-core computer, so, runtime aside, there are no problems that a multi-core computer can solve that a single-core can't.

In terms of something like graphics, literally everything that is on the GPU *could* be done on the CPU... if you are willing to wait long enough.

Comment: I'm assuming time is not a constraint. Thank you!

Comment: "literally everything that is on the GPU could be done on the CPU" - how about actually blitting the video memory onto the VGA pins? I know we're talking about hypothetical super-CPUs, but this would require a pretty decent CPU (you need to blit a bit once every 100 cycles or so if you're clocked at 1 GHz, and still do other stuff). Worse, it would require the kind of busses we don't have - unless you connect the VGA directly to the CPU, in which case it's called an integrated GPU, and it no longer counts as a generic CPU.

Comment: @JanDvorak I would actually say that this is not done by the GPU at all ;)

Comment: If time is not a constraint you could do all calculations by hand, pen and paper.

Comment: @mathreadler Yes, because the brain is Turing Complete. Something that turned into a [lengthy debate](http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/228643/37440) on Physics Stackexchange.

Comment: Could something which is not Turing complete build a Turing machine? Because we obviously have computers and they are (as far as I know) Turing complete.

Comment: @mathreadler Yes. A very restricted Turing machine could "print" a description of a universal Turing machine

Comment: Actually, @JanDvorak, generating VGA is quite simple and can be done in software on a lowly 16 MHz micro controller, as this project shows: http://www.pyroelectro.com/tutorials/arduino_basic_vga/

Comment: @mathreadler You would also need huge amounts of paper, ink and storage for those. Space complexity matters too, not just time complexity.

Comment: @JanDvorak: Funny you should mention that. The Amiga computers had a pretty sophisticated architecture as far as video (and other ports) was concerned, but when it came to driving the *serial* port (e.g. for modems), it was pretty much exactly that: It was the CPU's job to feed data to the port registers at the right speed. That's 1985 we're talking here, and it worked (on 7 MHz 68k single-core systems) up until the modems started to outpace the CPU. Serial expansion cards turned up, but yes, CPUs driving external ports has been done.

Comment: @mathreadler That is actually a more complicated question than it first appears.  A short answer might be "yes" because a specialized machine can construct a computer without requiring any turing complete tools to do so.  A longer answer might be "no," because the ability to construct a turing machine may imply that one has a larger turing machine that is in an "initialization" state where it constructs the rest of the state machine.  The full answer is even more complicated because we have never constructed a Turing Complete device.  We have developed abstract ideas for machines that are...

Comment: ... Turing complete, and made physical implementations of those ideas which appear, given near infinite resources, to be capable of emulating any Turing machine.  However, we have never constructed a computer which is *actually* capable of emulating any arbitrarily large  Turing machine -- there are limits to how long of a tape we can emulate without including odd effects of getting too large limited by the laws of physics,  like the computer collapsing under its own gravity.  The philosophical answer, then, would be "is the idea of a Turing machine, itself, a Turing machine?"

Comment: I love the discussion this answer spawned! However, its wording is kind of roundabout. I upvoted this and accepted @DW's due to its conciseness, while still coming to the same general conclusion.

Comment: @mathreadler obligatory: https://xkcd.com/505/

Comment: @mathreadler I think you should post that as an answer!

Answer (score 17):

As other answers have pointed out, a single CPU can always emulate multiple CPUs by slicing time and playing the role of each virtual CPU. This emulation will certainly calculate the correct answers.

In the real world, execution time may be important. It could mean the difference between a mediocre frame rate and a stellar visual experience. Or the difference between profit and loss in trading.

One pathological situation where a multiprocessor is *vastly* faster than a uniprocessor is where the processing is a data pipeline, context switching is expensive, and the machine code for each pipeline stage just barely fits in a CPU's cache.

Let me illustrate with some numbers. Suppose you have a data pipeline (3D rendering, etc.) that has 4 processing stages, each stage has 256 KiB of program code, and you conveniently have 4 CPUs with 256 KiB of L2 cache. If you try to run this processing on a single CPU, then switching between the 4 tasks will be expensive and involve heavy cache misses. On the other hand if you run it on a 4-core system, the calculation could potentially be very smooth, cache misses are minimal, and context switches are non-existent. (As a side note, this is related to the notion of pinning certain applications to certain cores - e.g. only doing OS kernel operations in one core, or TCP/IP handling, etc.)

Answer (score 8):

It's much harder to develop really nefarious data races with a single CPU.  I mean, sure, you can pull off tearing between words if you interrupt a single CPU, but can you build exotic scenarios where there is no single interleaving of threads which does what you want?

Okay, maybe making insidious bugs doesn't count as a valid use of multi-code advancements.  As it turns out, there's not much that mutli-core can do that single core cannot given time.  The reason is simple.  If you try to avoid those evil data races, you have to have synchronization points in your code.  If you model your code as a lattice of computations where ones inputs must be complete and synchronized before you can calculate and produce outputs, it's easy to see that a single CPU can simply work their way along the lattice, calculating the next available block of work.

In fact, if you can demonstrate that your algorithm can be solved by a Turing machine (which is virtually every algorithm we care about), it can be proven that the algorithm can be done by not only a single core CPU, but in fact a state machine with a very long piece of tape for memory!

The [CHESS](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/chess/) race detector actually leverages this to find race cases.  It runs everything singlethreaded and systematically explores all possible interleaves between threads, trying to find cases where a test fails because of a race case.  CHESS *depends* on the fact that you can run any multithreaded application on a single core.

The cases where you *need* multicore appear when you start stretching the limits of hardware.  The obvious one is when you have time constraints.  Some problems with realtime time constraints are impossible to do single core because they simply can't drive a single core's clock fast enough.  There's a reason CPUs climbed up to 4Ghz and then settled down a bit, preferring more cores at lower speeds.

A more exotic version of this timing constraint is in hard-real time systems.  In some hard real time systems, the service of interrupts is so demanding that you actually have to pick a multi-core CPU that lets you divvy the interrupts up across the cores, or you run into timing limitations.

Another limit arises with data busses.  Consider the Blue Gene/P as an example. JUGENE, a particular Blue Gene/P supercomputer, has 144 **terabytes** of memory.  They simply don't make single CPU computers that can access all of that memory.

Comment: Re, _They simply don't make single CPU computers that can access [that much] memory._  "Don't" is not the same as "can't".  You _could_ design and build a uniprocessor with 144 terabytes or more of main memory.  The only reason people don't is because of diminishing returns:  The incremental, practical value of adding more memory to a uni-processor design reaches a peak at some point and then drops off as the memory size grows, while the incremental cost remains constant.

Comment: @jameslarge That would be why that sentence came in the part of my answer discussing real life practical hardware, and why it did not appear in the first 2/3 of the answer which discussed the theoretical capacities.

Comment: "Don't" vs. "Can't" is illustrated by two systems in my basement. If I could physically add that much memory into their hardware configurations, their CPUs "could" access each byte. But I can't, so they "can't". The capabilities of the CPUs are beyond practicality.

Comment: I was thinking something like this answer. It seems that race conditions would be impossible (or happen 100% of the time) in a single-core environment. As for a practical application, I theorize that a software developer could engineer some unique form of copy protection by way of coding some weird race condition test that would always pass on the specific target hardware, but would fail on emulated hardware run by a single core. In this case, emulation by a multi-core system would probably pass sometimes, but unreliably.

Answer (score 6):

If you need to observe a process running on a single processing element without disturbing its real-time behavior (or as little as possible), like for benchmarking or activity logging, you'll probably need a separate processing resource.

Comment: Nice, concise example of something that would require precise emulation if not multiple processors

Comment: Hey is [this](http://cs.stackexchange.com/users/4853/yves-daoust) your account? Mayby you would like to merge it?

Answer (score 4):

The other answers adhere to the limited view of parallelism as "distributed concurrency". This gives some answers: in a clean model of computation à la Turing, multiple cores do not offer an advantage; the only advantage you may get is efficiency.

There is *the* one thing multiple processing units (PUs) can do that a single one can not, though: execute operations *in parallel*, that is *at the same time*.

That is very useful if you run multiple programs at the same time. Granted, it is only rarely that you absolutely need more than concurrent execution, and most uses come down to increased efficiency. But there *is* this difference.

Say you need to **process data sensor data** from multiple sources in real time. Whatever that means precisely in your application, one PU can only handle so many input streams concurrently without violating its response time limit. So you *need* multiple PUs once you have too many sensors for your current PU generation.

In the more classical realm, one maybe convincing example are **portfolio algorithms**. Say you have a problem for which you have multiple (say $k$) algorithms with orthogonal costs; good cases of one are bad cases for others. You can not quickly tell which one is best for a given input, though.

You can run *all* algorithms in parallel and abort once one finishes. If you have at least $k$ PUs, you get the *minimum* running time among all $k$ algorithms in the portfolio. With only one PU, you'd get $k$ times that, assuming a fair scheduler, plus all the overhead.

Answer (score 0):

from a CS pov, "multicore" is not that much different in theory than "distributed computing". the basic concept is "independent computing elements (that compute in parallel". so slightly rephrasing the question ("multicore" is not really exactly a theoretical concept in CS) leads to some other possibilities. as pointed out in other answers, sequential programming is equivalent to parallel programming from a CS pov. this goes back to the definition of the theoretical system for computing, namely a Turing machine. theoretical analysis of CS performance is ultimately in terms of TMs where the distinction of parallel vs sequential does not really apply (although there is some rough analogy with *multitape TMs*).

but considering this question less abstractly, distributed computing is indeed *superior* or possibly nearly even *required* for some problems involving *fault tolerance*. in this area there is a concept that it applies when/ where the independent computing elements are taken to have some degree of *unreliability*  (this is not really a universally applicable assumption for all contexts). here are several cases where fault tolerance is *improved* with or even *requires* independent computing elements.

- consider that each processor has an independent "[x]%" chance of failing during computation. a system can be devised whereby through communication the overall fault tolerance of the system is superior to individual components. this was applied many decades ago eg in Space Shuttle systems. more recently there are basic protocols designed to utilize it eg [Paxos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paxos_(computer_science)) which solve the so-called [consensus problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consensus_(computer_science)). a more down-to-earth example is Google which has a lot of proprietary algorithms to essentially build their supercomputer(s) out of individually unreliable elements coupled with fault-tolerant algorithms.
- Bitcoin involves distributed transactions to compute the ledger and that is not merely due to sheer processing load issues. the algorithm is carefully designed to thwart corrupt nodes. in short it "solves"/ implements the [Byzantine generals problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byzantine_fault_tolerance) which is not merely about maximizing parallel performance, it involves independent entities "checking" each other and "algorithmically/ cryptographically/ securely" rejecting invalid computations aka a sort of "cheating" or "corruption".
- a classic analysis of parallelism concludes there are about 7 "fundamental" problem pattern types that decompose into particular parallel execution breakdowns. see [The Landscape of Parallel Computing Research: A View from Berkeley](https://www.eecs.berkeley.edu/Pubs/TechRpts/2006/EECS-2006-183.html)
- there is some element of an open theoretical question here wrt performance considerations addressed in most other answers. the question of whether there are any problems that are "inherently faster" in parallel than sequential is also known roughly as the P=?NC problem where [NC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NC_(complexity)) is considered the class of "efficiently parallelizable" algorithms and [P](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P_(complexity)) is "efficient [sequential] algorithms"

Comment: I love this answer! I learned a lot from your examples :D

Comment: +1 for fault tolerance in mission-critical environments with radiation, -1 for lack of caps and redundancy.